# Using Blackberry webworks API within a Cordova application

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I'm building an app for Blackberry 10 using Cordova 2.8.0. I'm able to use cordova API, but I want to use some methods of the Webworks API, but although I add the webworks.js file in my html, the 'blackberry' object is not defined in my application. ¿How can I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the old WebWorks APIs have been ported to Cordova plugins [here](https://github.com/blackberry/cordova-blackberry-plugins)

What you need to do is not use the webworks.js file, but from within your project, run cordova/plugin add and the plugins you want to use.